# about adding a BufferedImage to the JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm still learning about the Java Swing toolkit and how it works. I'm researching different ways on how to add an image to my JFrame (via the JPanel) and found this tutorial ([HERE](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)). My question has to do with the way I setup my source code:

```
public class GraphicsPracticeDrawing extends JPanel{

    private BufferedImage img;

    public GraphicsPracticeDrawing() {
            this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            //Initialize(); //Program runs with no error/warning, but nothing appears in frame
    }

    //method initialized the BufferedImage
    public void Initialize() {
            try {
                    img = ImageIO.read(new File("images/star.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);

            Initialize(); //initialize the BufferedImage

            g.drawImage(img, 25, 25, null);
    }
```

}

If I was to take away the Initialize method and put the try/catch (to initialize my image) inside my constructor, my code compiles and runs but I end up with a blank window. If I put the try/catch in paint, like it's shown in my source my program runs perfectly fine, images loads, black background, and everything.

**TLDR;** Image1 is what happens when I initialize in the constructor, Image 2 is what happens when it runs fine and I initialize in my paint method. **([Take a Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbIij.jpg))**

Why can't I initialize my image in my constructor?

Comment: The behaviour you describe isn't what I'd expect under the scenario you describe.  Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that exhibits the behaviour you describe?

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#callbacks).

Comment: Are you sure your image is getting populated like you think when you read it from the constructor?  Look for exceptions being printed to the console.  You might try just letting the exception boil out of the constructor because e.printStacktrace() let's your program continue as if it worked when it's really in a bad state.

Comment: @chubbard , Im not sure what you mean if it gets populated when I call it to the constructor, by the way my program runs, it seems like the constructor isn't even being called.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor is getting called that's guaranteed if paint() is being called.  A blank screen like you're showing means there's an exception being thrown in your paint method.  Try this.  Comment out the image drawing code, and move your image loading code back to the constructor.  Now run it.  Do you see black?  If you do then you know it's painting without exception.  If not then you got another problem.  Check your console for exceptions.  If you got black uncomment the image drawing code.  Do you see gray?  Then I bet your image isn't loading in the constructor, and the paint method is throwing an exception.  Check your console and you'll see the exception why it's not working.  If not drop a break point on the IO.read line and look at the value you're getting.

You'll want to change paint() to paintComponent() as well.  I don't think that'll fix your problem, but you'll want to conform to Swing's painting architecture.

Now when you put the initialize() method in your paint method you are reading from the filesystem, creating a new image allocating memory for it, drawing it, and throwing it away, and doing all of that again when we draws the next frame.  In case you aren't aware of it that's creating a lot of trash for the garbage collector.  You want to read this image into memory once in the constructor, and paint from that memory from then on.

Comment: I don't get it, nothing appears in my console at all. So I'm guessing if paint is throwing an exception there's nothing catching it, and I don't know how to do that (unless you change the Java source code? again idk).

Comment: I seem to found a temporary solution I guess. 
(http://pastebin.com/RFxQivBQ)
I can Initialize in my constructor and the program will run fine, BUT only if i surround my call to paintComponent 'super' in a try/catch... I seriously don't know what's going on.

Comment: You've got something screwed up that we can't see.  The code you've shown must not be the problem, but I will take it and try it myself.  None of the workarounds you mention make any sense so if it's this mixed up there is something else to blame.  Your code you've shared doesn't appear to have any issues.  I will your code and try it out in my own program and get back with you.  Is there any threading going on that we should be aware of?

Comment: I actually found out that in my main class that extends JFrame, I was setting the frame visible BEFORE adding my JPanel component (shown in the source above). 
Apparently I can't do that because I was showing the JFrame before my JPanel could finish loading itself... I didn't know that.

Thanks for taking the time to offer help anyway.